# Where do i get the web client secret in firebase Google Login for android?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, google-signin

When i create the project first time. It gives the WEBclientID and Web Client secret. And i delete the the app beacause something did i wrong but google login webclient id  still there so i removed it and create the new android app but i cannot enable the google login beacuse of web client secret. So please suggest me where do i found and slove it. Please check the image below.
Thanks in advance.

[image: where do i found the web client secret.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem. we create the android project on firebase console. I figured out creating new Id and just looked on Google Console API credentials. It creates the two auth Id one for android and Second for web login. We need the Google web login **web client id** and **secret** for google login enable in firebase console. It works now.
Thank you for your replies Guys.

Comment: How do I get to this credentials page from the Project Overview?

Comment: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME}/authentication/providers 

Clic a provider and then open SDK settings

Answer (score 19):

You can find it from `google-services.json` class

[image]

Comment: This solved it for me - though keep in mind that you want the one with client_type 3 - the client_type 1 id didn't work for me.

Comment: What about the web client secret?

Comment: agree with @Elroid. somehow only `"client_type": 3` works. the attached screenshot is probably misleading.

Answer (score 19):

URL: https://console.firebase.google.com/
Please follow this breadcrumbs

**1.**  Authentication →  Google → Enable
[image]

**2.** Click on the Google Enabled link. Then opened the window below.

[image]

**3.** Click on **Web SDK configuration**

[image]

**4.** We can get Web Client ID here.

**5.** Copy the Web Client ID from this text box.

Answer (score 7):

In react-native android.

i had same issue after i completely deleted app(android) in firebase.

In newly created android app in firebase, i downloaded `google-services.json` and put it in `android/app/google-services.json` of my project.

i got the issues of `error code 10.`

I had solved `error code 10` problem in two issues.

**1.** i found out that webClientId was wrong, i put webClientId from Firebase `Authentication ---> Signin Method ---> Signin provider of Google login---> Web sdk` in my project (that cause the error).
Then i checked from google-services.json and select webClientId from this part

```
  ...
  "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "252222667222-26fq87bu3ha705mvbon55s7fffffff.apps.googleusercontent.com", //<-- select this
              "client_type": 3
            }

          ]
        }
      }  
   ...
```

put it in

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
  webClientId:"paste here clientId"})
```

then it solved my problem

**2.** In other issue, My debug key was mismatch, In firebase i was putting wrong debug SH1 using this command.

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Switch to `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-debug.apk` and used this command

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk
```

two SH1 were different, then put generated SH1 of app-debug.apk in firebase, then it fixed error code 10 issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Url:** `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials`

***Step 1:***

Click the below link. i.e. `Web client (auto ...)`

[image]

***Step 2:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can found this here client secret key here in firebase. : http://prntscr.com/jm0d3x

Comment: which one is web client secret server key or legecy server key

Comment: You can get  with https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nljm4.png and you need to create web client Id from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

And you also get your client_id from google-services.json file

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go to this website [Your keys credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)
and check if there is your web-secret key.

Comment: Is api key is Webclient Secret ? for android firebase project.

Comment: if you click on the web client id there is the client id and client key

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials  in here we only found the webclient secret for web not for androi. But in firebase console there asking the web client secret for google login enable. so i need to webclient secret on firebase. where did i find it.

Comment: hey, I don't get the question. You provided the screenshot for google authentication. There for you need the web client id and web client secret. You should found both here. Or you really deleted it even from there than please follow the explanation from @Mayur Patel in order to create a completely new credential entry

Answer (score 0):

you can find in google.service.json

Answer (score 0):

I found this data here:

Go to Authentication tab

[image]

-> Sign-in -> Google

[image]

Here you can find Client ID and Client secret

[image]